# asp.net, roles not getting assigned through forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms, roles

Another day with problems concerning roles in asp.net. So I'm currently trying to set up roles for my website. I use this piece of code for making the formsAuthentication ticket.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, //Ticket version
                p.firstName, //username
                DateTime.Now, 
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
                false, //true for persistant user cookie
                "Admin",
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

You can see that I'm adding the role "admin" to this person. p. is an object and firstname is a string. In the next piece of code I check wether the person got the admin role when he enters an admin site. if he's not an admin he has to be returned.

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin") != true)
     {
         Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
     }
```

the odd thing is that it returns me to the default page? anyone knows the answer?

PS. I know you have to set up authorization in the different locations in the web.config file. But if he doesn't even get the role it doesn't matter for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to get roles to work this way. The way it was designed to work is through the role manager. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx) for maore details.

One thing you may want to look at is the `cacheRolesInCookie` setting. If that is disabled, you can be sure that the default forms authentication stuff will not reload the roles from the authentication cookie.

Comment: I followed the link. Didn't know there was a configuration manager. So I added the roles I needed. But it still didn't work. I then added this to my login Roles.AddUserToRole(p.firstName, p.userRole); - Which worked very well. So they actually get the roles now. Why it didn't work adding them to the ticket in the first place I don't know. Also it seems like there a difference between HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole and User.IsInRole.

Comment: Oh and thank you for the cacheRolesInCookie I think it helped out a lot aswell :)

Comment: and btw. they changes that are made in the configuration manager, where do they end up? It didn't do anything to the config file it seems.

Comment: If you're using out of the box asp.net user management (as suggested in the article) your settings are probably stored in a user-instance database in ~/App_data.